# OS X Lion Server and FTP

Tags: osx-lion, ftp

I'm having trouble with my Lion Server with FTP.

I managed activating FTP via `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist` thats fine.
But now I want to control which user can access which directories on the server.

I created the sharings (for AFP) and enabled the sharing point for FTP with `sudo sharing -e Sites -s 110`

When I now login using FTP, I can access every directory on my system.
Is there any way to tell the sharing which user can access which folders?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but when I wanted to make the default directory on localhost point to a WordPress install for running an upgrade, I edited `/etc/ftpd.conf` and added this line:

```
chroot all /Users/User/Sites/WordPressSite
```

The documentation for `ftpd.conf` can be accessed by running `man ftpd.conf`. It looks like you can assign users to groups ("classes"), above I'm using the "all" class, but if you set up  users (see `man ftpusers`) you can probably set up the permissions you'd like per user.